# Woocommerce credit card drop down size

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I set up Paypal Pro with Woocommerce on my wordpress website to accept credit cards.
It works fine but the "year" and "month" drop down box for the user to enter their credit card info are very big and not aligned with the rest.
See image below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ElaIe.jpg

I am not sure how to change this.
Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Can you write some CSS to get them back into alignment? I think all you should need is to decrease the font-size.

Comment: Thanks. I am pretty sure you are right but I am not sure how to do this.

Comment: https://thethemefoundry.com/blog/how-to-customize-a-wordpress-theme/ is a pretty good beginners intro, though I'd strongly recommend reading the "learn how to use a wordpress child theme" link towards the end before you make any changes.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I fix my issue while opening my eyes to a whole new world! Thank you so much!